# An idiom for "seen clearly" or "plainly"

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a way to convey how multiple things are very well seen from a certain vantage point. In my native language there is a very appealing expression for that, that can be translated as "seen as in the palm of your hand", as in, it's right there, in front of you. Yet it seems in English "in the palm of your hand" has very different connotation, relating more to control than clarity. Is there any interesting figure of speech for "easy to see", "wide open and easy to see", or something of that nature?

*Edit*: in my example, I'm talking about physically seeing things with your eyes. Many of the proposed expressions are more frequently used when talking about "understanding" or "knowing" something that is not actually physical.

Answer (score 5):

[Plain as day](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plain+as+day) ( can also be used with the physical reference you are hinting at):

> - very obvious, quite clear.
>
>   - The secret to our success is as plain as day - make a good plan and stick to it.
> - easy to see or understand:
>
>   - I looked at the list and there, plain as day, was my name on the list of winners.

also,   [plain as the nose on your face](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plain+as+day) :

> - to be very obvious.
>
>   - There's no doubt that he's interested in her. It's as plain as the nose on your face.

(from www.dictionary.reference.com)

Comment: I'm voting for "nose on your face" since it involves a body part.

Answer (score 3):

["crystal clear"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crystal%20clear)

- "perfectly clear : able to be seen through completely"
- "The police officer gave me crystal clear directions."

> "Is that clear, sargeant?"
>
> "Crystal, sir."

It can also be used for its literal meaning:

> [Absolutely clear](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crystal+clear); pellucid: a crystal clear sky

Comment: Valid option. I feel like it's a bit cold though (the crystal that is), and wonder if there is more :)

Answer (score 0):

The only word that springs to mind is *panoramic*, which means any wide-angle view or representation of a physical space, whether in painting, drawing, photography, film/video, or a three-dimensional model.

To have a panoramic view, therefore, is to see any number of things at the same time. Digital cameras now allow the amateur photographer to capture panoramic views relatively easily. the noun-form, by the way, is *panorama*.

> - From our vantage point, we had a panoramic view of _____.
> - The photograph revealed a 360-degree panorama of the Grand Canyon.

An art-form featuring something close to a panorama is a diorama, some examples of which are found [here](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/diarama).

Comment: A panoramic view is notable for its breadth, not its clarity.

Comment: TRomano: Good point. Don